# How to pinPoint highchart grouped barchart variables

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, bar-chart, column-chart

Im trying to change the height of bars based on a slider that users can manually handle.

http://jsfiddle.net/h0ow9kLk/2/
Codes for the example:

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <form oninput="output1.value=slider1.value">
        <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" min="17" max="25"/>
        <output name="output1" for="slider1"></output>
    </form>
    <form oninput="output2.value=slider2.value" >
        <input type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2"  min="5000" max="5000" step="5"/>
        <output name="output2" for="slider2"></output>
    </form>
<button id="updater">Update</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Resistance', 'FuelConsumed', 'FuelCost', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Ship 1',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'Ship 1'
        }, 
                 {
            name: 'Ship 2',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'Ship 2'
        }]

    });
    var $slider = $("#updater");

                    $slider.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                var speed = $("#slider1").val();
                var weight = $("#slider2").val();
                var fuel;

                       if(weight == 5000){

                       if     (speed == 17){fuel = 41; }
                       else if(speed == 18){fuel = 51; }
                       else if(speed == 19){fuel = 60; }
                       else if(speed == 20){fuel = 75; }
                       else if(speed == 21){fuel = 80; }
                       else if(speed == 22){fuel = 100; }
                       else if(speed == 23){fuel = 120; }
                       else if(speed == 24){fuel = 138; }
                       else if(speed == 25){fuel = 153; }

                       }
                       else{ fuel = 0;} 
                        chartColumn.series[0].data[0].value[0].update(parseInt(fuel));
                    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);     
                });
});
```

So the update code:chartColumn.series[0].data[0].value[0].update(parseInt(fuel));

at the bottom is used to try and update the first bar. 
However i assume the path is wrong cause The bar isnt changing in height.

An example of what im trying to do is this
http://jsfiddle.net/ZmnWq/74/

Is there somewhere i can learn how to reach the data using the right path, and if possible can someone tell me how to change the data value.

This question sounds quite basic, but i really am new to this. All help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example just removing the values[0] will work.You need to assign your highchart to some object(in your example chartColumn) so you can later change the values based on that chart object. In your case it is undefined.

To add new point to your series you can use below code. The details can be found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint).

```
chartColumn.series[0].addPoint([x, 5], false, true);
```

To add whole new series you can add below code.

```
chartColumn.addSeries({
    name: "ship 3",
    data: [4,5,6,7,8]
}, false);

chartColumn.redraw();
```

To change the whole series with new values you can use setData which will automatically redraw the chart.

```
chartColumn.series[0].setData(data,true);
```

The working fiddle for your example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ahm6bdu/).

For more detail on axis update you can follow below documentation.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH hahaha i've really had no idea what to do for days!